# Is it possible to remove CPU controlled drivers from Mario Kart 8 Deluxe?

Tags: mario-kart-8-deluxe

Is it possible to remove CPU drivers from Mario Kart 8 Deluxe and if so could you tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it is, but not in the Grand Prix mode. If you select VS race mode you can customize if you want CPUs or not.

Comment: But how do i disable them? There are no options to disable them.
Please help... I'm new to the game and i wanted to learn the tracks without CPUs.